# How do I insert the data from a new csv to the bottom of an existing table in postgres? (Python)

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I am learning how to upload csv to a postgres database using python and have come up with the solution shown below:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import psycopg2

def db_connection():
    conn_string = "host=address dbname ='table' user='username' password='password'"

    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print('opened database successfully')

    cursor.execute("drop table if exists test_data;")
    cursor.execute("create table test_data \
    (id varchar,\
    name varchar,\
    address varchar)")

    #open the csv file, save it as an object
    my_file = open('/path/to/file/test_data.csv')
    print('file opened in memory')
    
    #upload to db
    SQL_STATEMENT = """
    COPY test_data FROM STDIN WITH
        CSV
        HEADER
        DELIMITER AS ','
    """

    cursor.copy_expert(sql=SQL_STATEMENT, file=my_file)
    print('file copied to db')

    cursor.execute("grant select on table test_data to public")
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print('table test_data imported to db completed')

db_connection()
```

However, that solution drops the table and recreates a new one with the new csv in question. I would like to create a script that adds on to the end of the table so that over time, it would conglomorate all previous csv's. Is there a SQL or python command that could do that, or is the best solution to find a way to merge all the files together prior and apply the same script to upload a singular large file each time? Rather than inserting new data to an existing table?

For example, I get a csv each day with 100 rows, so on day 1, my table in postgres would have 100 rows, day 10 would have 1000 rows, day 50 would have 5000 rows.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. If you don't want to drop the table, then remove the `DROP TABLE` statement at the beginning

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Apologies, the code there is in relation to what I've written so far with how I've found a way to upload a csv to postgres. Without the "DROP TABLE" part I get the 'table already exists' error. As for the question, I am trying to find a way to insert new data to an existing table without overwriting or remaking the table.

Comment: Well, then use `create table if not exists test_data ...`

Comment: Or skip both the `drop table` and the `create table` on subsequent runs - or put them in a separate script that you only run once at the beginning...